# Importing Python sympy module into Julia

Tags: import, julia

I have a Julia module in which I would like to import the Python function `sympy.physics.wigner.wigner_9j`. My minimal example module is as follows:

```
module my_module

using PyCall
using SymPy
export test

test()=sympy.physics.wigner.wigner_9j(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)

end
```

Then in my Julia notebook running:

```
using my_module
test()
```

gives

```
KeyError: key :physics not found
```

However adding to the notebook

```
@pyimport sympy.physics.wigner as sympy_wigner
sympy_wigner.wigner_9j(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
```

gives the correct output. For some reason using `@pyimport` inside modules gives errors, which I typically avoid by using an `__init__` inside my module, e.g adding to my_module.jl

```
const camb=PyNULL()

function __init__() # this should probably go in SFBBispectrum.jl
    copy!(camb, pyimport_conda("camb", "camb", "conda-forge"))
    pars=camb.CAMBparams()
end
```

which allows me to access `camb.CAMBparams`. Unfortunately I am failing to do something similar for `sympy.physics.wigner.wigner_9j`.

Answer (score 0):

It has been awhile, but does this help https://github.com/JuliaPy/SymPy.jl/blob/master/src/physics.jl